# What is more correct and why?

Tags: word-order, adverb-position

1. Technology helps us **better understand** more things.
2. Technology helps us **to understand better** more things.

Comment: Technology gives us a better understanding of more things.  (And if you believe that I've got some beach-front land in Utah to sell you.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) would be considered the normal way to express as fact that with technology to help us, we understand more things, and those things to a higher degree, than without it.

- I think there is an elided 'to' before 'better' in this version, i.e. "...helps us to better understand...".

(2) is a little stilted and could be misinterpreted. I think it says that technology helps us to understand things to a higher degree (but the number of understandable things is not changed). However, as I said, it's misunderstand able.

I would suggest avoiding (2). As to which is correct, it depends what the sentence was meant to convey.

Answer (score 0):

No (2) is indeed very stilted, and not a construction a native speaker would be tempted to use.

Ad if the sense of (2) is to understand more deeply a larger number of things (within the fixed set of understandable things), then I would move "better" to the end:

*Technology helps us to understand more things better.*

But as noted, if this is the specific intent, then the sentence is still liable to misunderstanding and ambiguity. It could be improved by dropping "more", or possibly changing it to "complex".